# Hook wc-cart to load on all pages in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Moved Woocommerce cart to work as a slide out instead of by default load on a single dedicated cart page.

Now am `wp_dequeue_script('wc-cart');` and manually loading required scripts and fragments and it's not optimal and i have issues with adding a coupon correctly for example.

If i could get Woocommerce to load all wc-cart data on all pages it would make things a lot easier.

**Is there a way to rewrite wc-cart function so it loads on all pages and not just on the dedicated cart page?**

**Update**
I know how to change core files for custom ones like

`function change_script_source()
{
    global $wp_scripts;
    $wp_scripts->registered['wc-cart']->src = get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/wc-cart.js';
}`

But i also would need to change how it hooks in so i can make it load all the data and fragments on every page not only on 'cart' specific one.

Comment: The cart is available... that's why the mini-cart is able to work on any page. Can you elaborate and maybe share some code?

Comment: @helgatheviking Does the mini cart have all function that the cart have? In my setup i remove the dedicated cart page and are running all cart functions in a slide out cart. At this point most functions is game except coupons etc.  Here is a screenshot to give a little better overview https://d17oy1vhnax1f7.cloudfront.net/items/3r2X0P0Z1X0R0h3D3w3E/Image%202016-09-02%20at%202.11.29%20PM.2e3m0U3T2E1P.png  ( It's on Swedish but rabattkod = Coupone function, Frakt = Shipping  etc )

Comment: No the mini cart is only showing the items in the cart and allows you to remove them. But that doesn't mean that it couldn't also have a coupon form added. Can you not enqueue the `wc-cart` script everywhere? And then write your own custom script to trigger some of it's functionality?

Comment: My point is that the cart data is probably already available. What data do you need?

Comment: Hey, @MathiasAsberg I am trying to do that same with my woocommerce store. 
Where you able to find any solution. I know it very old question, but can you share something which would help me.